# operate cells with other sheet with sheet().cells() format

Tags: vba, excel

I need iterate sheets that plus values in their cells in other sheet, the names of the "sheets" are save in sheet().index= man_prov and i iterate that. The code works but appears a window that requets "refresh values to the sheets" and the objetive cell value finally is "#¿NAME?". The code is:

```
For k = pfila_mprov + 1 To ufila_mprov

    sn = Sheets(man_prov).Cells(k, 2)
    h = Sheets(sn).Index

    Select Case k
    Case ufila_mprov
        suma = suma & " " & Sheets(h).Name & "!" & Sheets(h).Cells(4, 4).Address & ""
    Case Else
        suma = suma & " " & Sheets(h).Name & "!" & Sheets(h).Cells(4, 4).Address & ","
    End Select

Next k

Sheets(pro_pack).Cells(16, 4).Formula = "=sum(" & suma & ")"

End If
```

i need use the format sheets().cell() to iterate, and finally plus the values saved in "suma" .
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to construct a string that consitutes range addresses in different sheets for summation? Is that correct?  I haven't looked properly but be careful with referring to sheets by index, in case they get moved around.

Comment: Difficult to debug without some data and more of the code. I have guessed at declarations and put some dummy data in and works for me.

Comment: I solved the problem i need a " ' " before and after Of the name of the sheet: 
    suma & " ' " &                               sheets(h).name & " ' " &      "!".....etc

The message of "refresh the values of sheets" happens because VBA takes the sheets(h).name as a workbook name without the " ' ".
Thanks for the answer.